# Hexagon grid gets cut off when generated outside of the JFrame

Tags: java

I'm programming a hex-grid based game where you click on adjacent tiles to the player and when the player moves the map/grid moves in the opposite direction (using setLocation() on the jpanel inside the main jframe) so that, relative to the screen, the player is still centered.

When I pass in a big enough number of hexagons some of the grid generates outside of the jframe. When this happens, I can still make the player move around and open the menu and change player skins, but when moving north on the grid (when the top of the grid is what got generated outside the jframe) the grid just gets cut off and ends before the whole hexagon gets repainted.

I was wondering if there was a way to fix this that maybe I've simply just overlooked. My first thought was to delete and then regenerate the grid with new x,y coordinates each time the player moves and not use setLocation() at all, but I feel like that would be very inefficient and more of a brute force solution (last resort). I just feel like there has to be a more elegant or efficient way. I've tried using setSize(), setMinimumSize(), and setPreferredSize() methods to try and make the jpanel or the jframe's content pane bigger.

Picture to help:

[image: You can see that I can obviously highlight those hexagons and even move onto them and move back off as illustrated by the player's path being shown.]

Comment: So do you want the player to not be able to move past a point or do you want the map to move if the player gets to the end? It's a little unclear.

Comment: Please restate your question (in a single, short paragraph), or it's probably going to get closed as unclear.

Comment: Do you call `repaint` on the JPanel after you invoke `setLocation`?

Comment: I have as much as I do because I didn't want there to be any confusion. And yes I do call repaint whenever I setLocation.

Comment: and CodingNinja, the map moves everytime the player moves. the player should not be able to walk completely off of the grid, but the jframe cuts off the top part of the grid so you cant even see the player when you move past where the grid gets cut off.

Comment: Some code which handles you boundaries and paint commands would really help.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely should not be moving the JPanel around inside the JFrame, because the JPanel is essentially your work area, and since your work area is always a specific size, if you move it, part of it is going to be outside the JFrame, and part of the JFrame is going to be empty.

That being said, you must be redrawing the tiles every frame if you're able to move the character and use the ui, etc. Simply moving the x, y coordinates won't slow that process down at all. You mentioned that some of the hexagons were getting rendered outside of the JFrame, so you could implement a check that only renders the tiles on the actual screen.

Alternatively, if the map never changes, you could render the entire map to an image (or several chunks), and then each frame just draw that image in its appropriate location. I don't think this would save you that much time, but you could look into it.